# Dismiss Rg.Plugins.Popup on scroll down in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues) plugin in my xamarin forms app. It is a nice plugin for modal dialogs. However, I am looking to dismiss the dialog when user scrolls down. (Most dialogs in iOS has this behavior of closing with scrolling down).

XAML inside Popup page.

**Option 1**

```
 <pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             HasSystemPadding="True"
             CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="False"
             x:Name="MyPage"
             x:Class="wQuran.Views.Today.PrayerTimesSettingsPopupPage">
<Frame Style="{DynamicResource PopupFrame}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*" Style="{DynamicResource BaseGrid}">
            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource PopupTitleBoxView}"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,30" HeightRequest="40" Padding="10">
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{DynamicResource PopupTitleLabel}"/>
                <ImageButton Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource DialogCloseImageButton}" Command="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**Option 2.**
Updated XAML and added the Frame inside ScrollView

```
<ScrollView Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
....
</ScrollView>

private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollY > 100)
            {
                itemViewModel.CloseDialogCommand.Execute(null);   
            }
        }
```

In option 1 I don't have the scroll, so the plug in works with default behavior, but I have no way to close the dialog in scroll.

In option 2, I added the frame inside the scrollview to check for Y scroll and dismiss the dialog. The Scrolled event never fires. Additionally, I cannot close the dialog when clicking outside the modal.

After all, my question is how to dismiss the dialog while scrolling down?

Answer (score 0):

> After all, my question is how to dismiss the dialog while scrolling down?

I guess that you want to close PopupPage when ScrollView scroll ending. If yes, please take a look the following code:

```
<pages:PopupPage
x:Class="FormsSample.simplecontrol.Page16"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
<StackLayout
    Padding="20,0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Frame
        Padding="0"
        BackgroundColor="CadetBlue"
        CornerRadius="10"
        HeightRequest="100">
        <ScrollView Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled">
            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="First Popup Page"
                    TextColor="Black" />
                <Label Text="Hello Xamarin Guys" TextColor="Red" />

                <Label Text="This is Very Awesome Popup Plugins For Xamarin forms" TextColor="LightBlue" />
                <Button Text="Close" TextColor="Black" />
                <Image Source="a11.jpg" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Frame>

</StackLayout></pages:PopupPage>

 private async void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollView scrollView = sender as ScrollView;
        double scrollingSpace = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.Height;

        if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY) // Touched bottom
            // Do the things you want to do
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Actually no, I want the modal should be scrollable not the content. We should be able to scroll up and down the modal. Modal scroll is common behavior in iOS for any dialog you open. (e.g) Open Account modal in App store in iPhone and this modal is scrollable where if you scroll down and reach certian limit it will dismiss.

Comment: @ARH **Open Account modal in App store in iPhone and this modal is scrollable where if you scroll down and reach certian limit it will dismiss.**  I think this is natively supported by ios, it is not related to Rg.Plugins.Popup.